# Certificate verification when using virtual environments

Tags: python, python-requests, virtualenv

I have a root CA certificate installed on my machine and all is fine when issuing a requests when using the system install of the requests library:

```
$ python -c 'import requests; print requests.get("https://example.com")'
<Response [200]>
```

However if I issue the same request from within a virtual environment the certificate verification fails:

```
$ python -c 'import requests; print requests.get("https://example.com")'
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Using `requests.certs.where` I can see the system install uses the systems CA bundle and the virtual environment uses the CA bundle shipped with requests:

```
$ python -c "import requests; print requests.certs.where()"
/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

$ (venv) python -c "import requests; print requests.certs.where()"                                                            
.../venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/cacert.pem
```

Is there another solution to picking up the system certs without providing the path on each request when using `virtualenv`, i.e:

```
>>> requests.get("https://example.com" verify="/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system package had been installed via the systems package manager and had been modified so that `requests.certs.where` returned the systems CA bundle `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`. Inside the virtual environment `requests` is installed via pip so uses the bundled `cacert.pem`.

Looking at source for [`requests.certs`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/certs.py) pointed me at [`python-certifi`](https://github.com/certifi/python-certifi). The solution I used to solve my issue was to create a package in the style of `python-certifi` containing the root certificates for the sites I need.

```
from my_certifi import where
requests.get("https://example.com" verify=where())
```

Now any requests to `https://example.com` will be verified without the need for any system dependant modifications or configuration.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to insert a specific CA certificate to your CA bundle of virtualenv, you can just append to it:

```
openssl x509 -in $specific_ca.crt -text >> $virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem
```